# cannot realign legend in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I am writing a code using rmarkdown and displaying the output as an html document. I have a data frame from which I want to create a bar graph. Now the legend is too long so it overlaps and covers part of the graph. I have tried a lot of things but am unable to align the label direction, legend direction. I am only able to remove the legend using (legend.position = "none"). I cannot even move the legend left, right, bottom or top using "legend.position". Is there a way to either decrease the font of labels or align them vertically? **Basically something to make the legend smaller or move it somewhere where there might be more space to avoid any sort of overlapping...**

Can someone please help me?

Below is the code:

```
create_bar_graph <- function(ggdata, ggaxis, ggfac) {
       p <- ggplot(ggdata %>% filter_(!is.na(ggaxis)), 
                   aes_string(x = ggaxis, fill = ggaxis)) + 
                   geom_bar() + 
                   facet_wrap(ggfac) +
                   labs(
                       # title = "Insurance", 
                       y = "Nb of respondent") + 
                   # coord_flip() +
                   scale_fill_brewer(palette = "PuRd") +
                   guides(fill = guide_legend(title = NULL)) +
                   theme(axis.text.x =                        
                   element_blank(),legend.position = "none")
      return(p)
}

caption_func <- function(text){
     htmltools::tags$caption(style = 'caption-side : top;
                             text-align = center',
                             htmltools::h3(text))
}
data = data.frame(
           product = rep(c("A","B"),each = 6),
           disease = rep(c("a) Partial onset seizures",
                           "b) Partial onset seizures with secondary generalization",
                           "c) Primary generalized tonic-clonic seizures (PGTCS)",
                           "d) I don't know the type of Epilepsy I have")),3)

ggplotly( create_bar_graph(data,"disease", "product"))
```

The output I have is something  like this (the stack height from the code above may differ from the height in image but everything else is same):
[image]

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Hi, sorry about that. I had been stuck on this for quite a while and searched a lot of threads and tried whatever I could find but nothing worked and now I am exhausted and frustrated. I know this isn't acceptable and am sorry for that.

Comment: It's ok, you can edit the question. It's also quite important to clarify that you are using `plotly`, not just `ggplot`.

Comment: Was there a feature that you wanted from ggplotly, or would it suit your needs to just use ggplot?

Comment: just ggplot would also be fine

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that my problem can be sorted out using "width" parameter from plotly. I tried increasing the width and luckily the legend kept shifting to the right.

```
ggplotly( create_bar_graph(data,"disease", "product"),width = 1000)
```

Thanks to all who spend their valuable time having a look at my problem. I guess I posted it before trying enough. Sorry for the trouble guys.